# Issue with docker-compose support while installing VECTR

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to install VECTR on the GCP Ubuntu instance and following the official writeup for the same.

I used apt-get to install requirements (docker-ce, docker-ce-cli, containerd.io, docker-compose, unzip) on Ubuntu (GCP).

But while trying to run `docker-compose up -d` , I am getting issues with the docker-compose version.

> ERROR: Version in "./docker-compose.yml" is unsupported. You might be seeing this error because you're using the wrong Compose file version. Either specify a version of "2" (or "2.0") and place your service definitions under the services key, or omit the version key and place your service definitions at the root of the file to use version 1.

Changed docker-compose.yml file and padded version to 2.
But now getting a different issue:

> ERROR: Invalid interpolation format for "ports" option in service "tomcat": "${VECTR_PORT:-8081}:8443"

Comment: You're getting errors from your `docker-compose.yml` file, but you haven't included the file in your question. That makes it very difficult for us to tell what's going on. Please update your question to include the relevant file.

Answer (score 0):

The docker-compose distro has been deprecated.  Instead, you should install docker-compose-plugin. This is going to be more important over time because the versions are getting very far apart (currently 1.25.X vs 2.6.X). Instead of executing docker-compose up, you will now execute the command:

```
docker compose up
```